# sharepoint 2013 get ID of a user

Tags: javascript, user-profile-property, csom, jsom

I am looking to figure out a way to get the ID of a user, given their name, so that I can use it in a call to `/_layouts/15/userdisp?ID=n`, where 'n' is the ID of the user to redirect the person who is viewing the page to another person's Profile page. I am using JavaScript. I will not know the url of the mysites site hence using this method rather than the one using the MySites method. I am on a search results page not a person search results page.

I am using SharePoint 2013 SP1 April 2015 CU.

Answer (score 3):

you can use:

```
<script>
    var userId = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
</script>
```

[_spPageContextInfo is your new best friend](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2013-2-_sppagecontextinfo_is_your_new_best_friend.aspx)

Comment: Keep in mind that the user profile url requires the claims encoded login name (at least O365 does), and that `_spPageContextInfo` returns the user's id _for that particular site collection_.  **edit:** just noticed that this is _not_ the my site url he's looking for.  Great answer!

Comment: is _spPageContextInfo.userId not the id of the user who is browsing the page not the id of a particular user ?

Comment: pls can you provide more details? I did not understand

Comment: _spPageContextInfo.userID is the ID of the current user.  ie the person who is browsing the page

Comment: The questions how to get the ID of another user (not the currently logged in user)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to <strike>do not reinvent the wheel</strike> resolve personal site url from user login name directly instead of constructing the url to display form of User Information list (`/_layouts/15/userdisp?ID=<user id>`).

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve user personal site url:

```
function navigateToPersonalSite()
{

  SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.ClientContext', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.js'));
  SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.userprofiles.js'));
  SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['SP.ClientContext', 'SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager'], function(){

    getUserProperies(loginName,
       function(properties){
          var url = properties.get_personalUrl();
          window.location.href = url;
       }, 
       function(sender, args) {
          //handle errors...
       }
    );

   });
}   



function getUserProperies(loginName,success,failed)
{
   var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(ctx);
   var properties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(loginName);
   ctx.load(properties);
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
       function(){
          success(properties);
       }, 
      failed);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var loginName = "i:0#.f|membership|jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com";
navigateToPersonalSite(loginName);
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim - I need the url because it is a link to the personal details where, if the usewr wants to, they can click on it and go to the personal details.  otherwise the link just stays on the page,

Comment: Hi Vadim - do we not need promises here if we just want the url, and not to redirect to another site ?

Comment: Since executeQueryAsync is async method, it could be invoked as a promise or callback as in my case

Comment: do you have an example as a promise ?

Comment: At the moment the code is going through twice, once with no results and then later when the query has finished with the results in.  So on my screen it comes out as a null url.

Comment: This code is being run within a SharePoint Search Display Template.  Does this make any difference to anything? Thanks Nigel

Answer (score 1):

You can use [REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx):

```
var getUserId = function() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "<site url>/_api/web/siteusers?$select=Id&$filter=Title eq '<user's name>'",
        type: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata', // JSON Lite should be available in SP1.  If not, use odata=verbose instead
            'content-type': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' // same thing, replace with odata=verbose if this doesn't work
        }
    });
}

var userId = '';
getUserId().done(function(d){
    userId = d.value[0].Id;
    var userDispUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + '/_layouts/15/userdisp?ID=' + userId;
    window.location.href = userDispUrl; // or do whatever you want with the ID, but do it in this callback.
});
```

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx) focuses on the users, groups and roles REST API.

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: It works fine but....

Comment: But...? Is there something you don't understand?

Comment: Yes why, when I step from getUserId().done(function(d){userId=d[0].Id;}) do I lose the value of userId ? and cannot use it elsewhere.

Comment: See my edit.  You can either make userId a globally scoped variable (excessive), or simply do what you need to in the callback function.